# setfacl not working with brace expansion

Tags: linux, bash, acl, brace-expansion

They Symfony docs have you issue two commands to set permissions on the cache folders:

`setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx app/cache
setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx app/cache`

A more efficient way would be:

`setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m d:u:www-data:rwx app/cache`

This works for me on Ubuntu 12.04. Trying to use brace expansion, however, doesn't seem to:

`setfacl -R {"-m ","-m d:"}u:www-data:rwx app/cache`

outputs:

`setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 1`

If I echo the command with braces, and then run the output, it works:

`echo setfacl -R {"-m d:","-m "}g:deploy:rwx . | source /dev/stdin`

What gives? Why won't the expansion run on its own?

Answer (score 0):

The two `-m` arguments aren't being word-split. They are being passed as one argument to `setfacl`.

When you echo the string through they are.

```
$ c ()
{
    printf 'argc: %s\n' "$#";
    printf 'argv: %s\n' "$@"
}
$ c setfacl -R {"-m ","-m d:"}u:www-data:rwx app/cache
argc: 5
argv: setfacl
argv: -R
argv: -m u:www-data:rwx
argv: -m d:u:www-data:rwx
argv: app/cache
$ echo setfacl -R {"-m ","-m d:"}u:www-data:rwx app/cache | c $(< /dev/stdin)
argc: 7
argv: setfacl
argv: -R
argv: -m
argv: u:www-data:rwx
argv: -m
argv: d:u:www-data:rwx
argv: app/cache
```

That being said, I'm not sure why, offhand, it wouldn't be word split. I would have thought expansion order would have word split the results but .